# (PDE / Eclipse Plug-in Development) How to set layout SWT & JFace?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pde

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6q0.png

This layout is `GridLayout`.

`Text`, `Label` and `Button` is element of SWT.
So, there use set `GridData`.

But `TreeViewer` is a element of JFace.
It is can't use `GridData`.

I Want to `TreeViewer`'s size is fill horizontal.

Comment: English grammar, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an underlying SWT Tree component under JFace TreeViewer. You Can do it like this:

```
treeViewer.getTree().setLayoutData(data);
treeViewer.getTree().setLayout(layout);
```